# Call function inside ng-repeat to retrieve value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-init

I'm having this situation I'm iterating over a json response from an endpoint:

chunk of controller code:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://mywebsite.com/api/v1/stores/'
}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.stores = data;
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.name = 'Error!';
});
```

and on my html view side I've got this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="store in stores">
        <td>{{store.name}}</td>
        <td> {{store.type}} </td>
        <td><span ng-repeat="client in retrieveClientName(store.client_id)">
                {{client.name}}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>{{store.address}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

As you can see I'm trying to retrieve the client name using a function that receives an **store.client_id** from the values inside the **stores** array. Normally using a function triggered by a ng-click will be easy but how can I achieve this "on the fly" while I'm iterating?.
Because executing this I get a kind of infinite loop that breaks all apart.

here is the code of the function that returns client name on the controller side:

```
$scope.retrieveClientName = function(id) {
   $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'http://mywebsite.com/api/v1/clients?client_id='+id
      }).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          return $scope.clients=data;
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.name = 'Error!';
      });
    }
```

I have also try using mg-init directive

```
<td  ng-init="clients=retrieveClientName(store.client_id)"><span ng-repeat="client in clients">{{client.name}}</span></td>
```

Comment: why do you repeat here ?`<span ng-repeat="client in retrieveClientName(store.client_id)">
                {{client.name}}
            </span>`
isnt clientName a string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be get all data when you get the `stores` back

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://mywebsite.com/api/v1/stores/'
}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.stores = data;
    angular.forEach($scope.stores, function(store){
        $scope.retrieveClientName(store.client_id).then(function(clients){
             store.clients = clients;
        });
    });
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.name = 'Error!';
});
```

---

Edit: I would change the structure a bit for cleaner code

```
$scope.retrieveClientName = function(store) { // pass in store so we can attach results here
   $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://mywebsite.com/api/v1/clients?client_id='+store.client_id
   }).
   success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      return store.clients = data; // attach result in object
   }).
   error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.name = 'Error!';
   });
}

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://mywebsite.com/api/v1/stores/'
}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.stores = data;
    angular.forEach($scope.stores, function(store){
        $scope.retrieveClientName(store); // no need .then here
    });
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.name = 'Error!';
});

<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="store in stores">
        <td>{{store.name}}</td>
        <td> {{store.type}} </td>
        <td><span ng-repeat="client in store.clients"> <!-- use data here -->
                {{client.name}}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>{{store.address}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody
```

Comment: This will break without using a promise solution doesn't it ?

Comment: What do you mean by a "promise solution"? `$http` itself is already returning a promise itself, so you are already using one without mentioning it.

Comment: I'm getting "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" that's what I thought some kind of callback was missed

Comment: Oh... adding a `return` before `$http` in the function should handle that. I've updated all code so it can work without `.then` and looks much cleaner.

Comment: great! it works fine, excellent explanation of all, good solution for my understanding

Comment: You're welcome! I think you'll soon come across the usefulness of `promise` =)

Answer (score 1):

You must understand that $http jest asynchronous, so Your response will be back after all ng-repeat, so such thing must be done in controller in **$q.all** and after that render view with ng-repeat.

So do foreach on stores and in foreach add to array, next use this array in $q.all, after $q.all render view.

Answer (score 1):

The `retrieveClientName` function is wrong: the $http return a promise, the return value of success callback is not the return value of the function and you can't bind the ng-repeat to a promise, try this one:

```
$scope.retrieveClientName = function(id) {
    return $resource('http://mywebsite.com/api/v1/clients?client_id='+id).query();
}
```

Don't forget to include the ngResource dependency.

Comment: looks great but I don't have find any example that matches with my case